# Raise sink up off pedestal

Tags: sink, bathroom-fixtures, epoxy

We have a bathroom sink that sits on a pedestal. We are due for a full bathroom renovation in next couple years, but I need a way to deal with a problem until then.

The sink was installed wrong (and/or the house is settling) such that the sink isn’t level when it is resting on the pedestal. It’s gotten so bad that not all the water drains out of the sink, because the lowest spot in the sink isn’t the drain. I’d like a way to deal with that for next year or two.

I thought of propping up the sink with webbing and some boards until it is level, and then filling in the 1/2” gap created (see photo) between the sink and pedestal with some epoxy. But not sure if that would work well, or if others have better ideas.

If I did the epoxy approach, any pointers on what kind to buy?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, that photo was right-side-up. Not sure how it flipped.

Comment: I've rotated it for you, but I'm low rep on this particular stack so higher rep users (or yourself) will have to accept my edit before you can see it.

Answer (score 2):

Epoxy would work, though it would be troublesome to get in there.

If it was me and I knew that the sink would be trashed after a couple of years, I'd just support the lip, get a tube of normal white silicone caulk and start loading up the crack. Let it dry for 24 hours with the support in place and then you're good to go. (The silicone will compress a tiny bit, but not much.)

Comment: I agree, but I'd cheapskate it even further - silicone $£€ 10, decorator's caulk $£€ 1. It's not really going to get wet enough under there to demand silicone. Save 9 bucks.

Comment: The one concern I have is that the pedestal has relatively thin walls. So I’m a bit worried there’s not enough surface area to keep the stresses low enough in silicone or caulk. But I will probably try that first, given low cost.

Comment: I'd assume that the amount of force needed to fully compress caulk used as a stop-gap filler in this way would be more than sufficient to pull the basin's screws out of the wall first, so i wouldn't worry about it too much ;) Push some up between basin & wall if you can get any in, for a bit of extra support.

Comment: Support the bowl with a plastic shim or two (as Jasen noted in his answer), then some cheap-o caulk to hide the gap.

Answer (score 2):

stick some plastic wedges in there and glue them in place with epoxy or panel glue.